# How do I get the hash of the first commit of this year?

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull together some stats on our codebase which consists of quite a few repos.

Is there a way to identify the hash of the first commit after a given date (in this case, Jan 1, 2015)?

Answer (score 3):

This did it!

```
git log --since "01-01-2015" --date-order --pretty="%H" | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git log command to get some history included with the grep command to filter it down. I did something like this to only get matches from 2015 and then grab the last one. You can do something like this with the Git Bash program in windows if you're not on linux.

```
git log | grep -B 2 2015 | tail -3
```

This does a git log (history with hashes, authors, and dates), gets the 2 lines about the date (to include the hash), and then grabs the last 3 lines, which will be the earliest in the year 2015.

You can also do some more work to get just the hash, pulling the hash alone from the first line of the results of the command above.

Manual for git log:

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History